# Create and step-through (private) npm package from ES6 source

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I am developing an application that contains two main parts:

1. an `express.js`app that (more or less) implements the Strategy pattern by selecting the desired
2. Adapter library for manipulating data from a given source to a common interface

Due to corporate organizational demands, this turns out to be a relatively complex exercise in repository management. #1 and #2 live in separate git repos. As currently implemented, #2 is `npm install`ed via a `browserify` `postinstall` hook in #1's `package.json`. This has some disadvantages, in particular, it makes debugging the library code from #2 more difficult, since from #1's perspective, #2 is a single `babel` transpiled js file, rather than the ES6 code that we wrote.

How do I set up an `npm` package for #2 s.t. I can step through the code in #2 during a debug session on #1? I've never created an `npm` package, and it seems like this is a little outside the norm.

I'd be glad enough to remove the `babel` dependency, but would rather not link that work to creating the repo with source maps. `browserify` will be eliminated when the npm repo is created. 
So I specifically need to know about:

- creating the source maps
- compiling the source for the repo
- using different compiled versions for different environments (prod/dev/etc)
- probably other things that I don't know about but you do because you're more experienced with this process

Comment: I'm confused about why browserify is involved in an express.js app?  Also are there test suites that test #2 directly ?

Comment: Also, are you using [source maps](http://www.2ality.com/2015/04/node-es6-transpiled.html) in your debugging?

Comment: there's no _good_ reason for browserify's involvement, except that this work  involves migrating from a browser-based to a proxied-request based adapter model. broweserify is going to go as part of this work. There are test suites that exercise #2. And I intend to use source maps in the solution we're discussing here! Thanks!

Comment: Well, if your getting rid of browserify, can't you also get rid of Babel and just run the ES6 code directly in node.js?  Or, if you're still using Babel, then just configure source maps so the debugger can map to your ES6 source.

Comment: right, and what's that configuration look like?

Comment: If your whole question is really just how to make an NPM module from a private repository so you can use NPM install to use it with other modules (and all this other stuff is just confusing us), then there are lots of sites that describe how to do that.  Here's the [NPM link](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) on the subject.